# How to move the first html element if the second html element is over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for my bad english :)

1) Sidebar moves to the right (Start Left position = -270, End position = 0);

2) Header contains logo  with position:absolute

How to move the logo div to the right if the sidebar is above the logo?

```
<div class="logo">
<img src="http://placehold.it/70x70">
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
Menu item 1<br/>
Menu item 2<br/>
Menu item 3<br/>
Menu item 4<br/>
Menu item N<br/>
</div>


.logo {
  position:absolute;
  left:220px;
  z-index:2;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color:blue;
  height:350px;
  width:270px;
  position:absolute;
  left:-260px;
}


$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".sidebar").click(function() {
        $(".sidebar").animate({left: "0px"}, 500);
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ybj4dzn/

Comment: Please update your question with your codes, such `html` or `css`. better provide a `jsfiddle` demo to get better help here!

Comment: jsfiddle.net/6ybj4dzn need move logo div to right if sidebar above the logo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this simple example I set up:
https://jsfiddle.net/0oon722z/

Only added the following line:

```
  $(".logo").animate({left: $(".sidebar").width()}, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks! How to to move logo div to right if sidebar is above the logo

Comment: Do you really need to move it to the left thought it needs to go to the right? In your fiddle the blue div overlaps the logo! So why move it to the left if its not even visible?